# What are the alternatives to "python3 sample_program.py &" via ssh?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, remote-server

I am running a python script `sample_program.py` on python via ssh. I log into the machine, and run

```
python3 sample_program.py &
```

and log off with the command 'exit'. Unfortunately, the script stops running after a few minutes.

What else could I use to run python scripts remotely and not keep the Terminal open?

Comment: I used to use GNU `screen` pretty frequently . . .

Comment: @mgilson For a remote application via `ssh`, do I need `screen` downloaded or the remote host computer?

Comment: You can nohup http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/nohup-execute-commands-after-you-exit-from-a-shell-prompt.html https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup

Comment: @ShanZhengYang -- Yes, `screen` would need to be installed on the remote computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## nohup

```
nohup python3 sample_program.py &
```

is the simplest way (`man nohup`):

> **nohup** - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

and IMHO it is installed everywhere.

Comment: `nohup` appears to work far better simply `python3 sample_program.py &` alone. Why would that be?

Answer (score 1):

#### at

You can use the `at` command.  The `at` execute commands at a later time. The `at` utility shall read commands from standard input and group them together as an at-job, to be executed at a later time.
For more information, options, examples, and others see the [Ubuntu Manpage Repository][1]

Example:

```
at now +8 hours -f python3 sample_program.py
```

You can also use convenient shorthands, like `tomorrow` or `noon`, as in

```
echo "tweet fore" | at teatime
```

#### Independently of any terminal

```
ssh root@remoteserver '/root/backup.sh </dev/null >/var/log/root-backup.log 2>&1 &'
```

You need to close all file descriptors that are connected to the ssh socket, because the ssh session won't close as long as some remote process has the socket open. If you aren't interested in the script's output (presumably because the script itself takes care of writing to a log file), redirect it to `/dev/null` (but note that this will hide errors such as not being able to start the script).

Using `nohup` has no useful effect here. `nohup` arranges for the program it runs not to receive a HUP signal if the program's controlling terminal disappears, but here there is no terminal in the first place, so nothing is going to send a SIGHUP to the process out of the blue. Also, `nohup` redirects standard output and standard error (but not standard input) to a file, but only if they're connected to a terminal, which, again, they aren't.

#### You can set a cron job.

For example if now the time is 14:39:00 and today is friday, 30 august, you can add the following cron job (to be executed after 8 hours) in your crontab file using `crontab -e` command:

```
39 22 30 8 5  /path/to/python3 /path/to/sample_program.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the shebang to the start of your scripts!

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3
```

Give it permissions to execute.

```
chmod +x python3
```

Execute remotely!

```
sudo nohup ./python3 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

This way it will run as a background process and detach from the terminal, and you will not be writing an unnecessary nohup.out file.

You DO NOT even need the .py file extension in Linux, nor do you need to use more characters than needed:

```
{ python3 python3.py }
```

is just the same with

```
{ ./python3 }
```

It just needs the shebang and to be executable.