# How to exit AWS shell without killing job

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, ssh, nohup, aws-shell

I am running a long python process on a Amazon Web Service shell, say it is

```
python sample.py
```

When I exit the shell, it will kill the process, so I tried putting it in the background with `nohup python &`.

I exited the shell and when I came back, I typed `ps -ef | grep python`, and the process was still there, however it was no longer printing any output (the job keeps writing output). I tried `fg <job_number>` and I got "no such job".

The result for `ps -ef | grep python` is

```
ubuntu    2433     1 81 02:55 ?        00:01:53 python sample.py
```

Is the process still running? How do I keep checking its output?

Comment: The nohup.out file in the directory you executed it.

Comment: Fantastic! It was so simple. If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the alternatives to "python3 sample\_program.py &" via ssh?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36510091/what-are-the-alternatives-to-python3-sample-program-py-via-ssh)

Comment: Actually, that question is different. I know how to exit and keep the program running, but I did not know how to look at the running program after I am back in.

Comment: why not use screen/tmux or others?